# simulating website login in delphi app FMX

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-xe6, delphi-xe7

How can I invoke a website's click event, or rather more simply, log into a website via POST and delphi? For example, I am in a franchise league with some friends for the PS4/XBox1 game Madden 15. Their companion app on store is really just a link to the website, and the website quite frankly, is clunky and hard to navigate on mobile. I want to replicate the site - tailoring to my needs of course - using Delphi in the form of a mobile app. My first hurdle is logging in. My planning was that I would just have web browser in the background of the app that logs-in/loads HMTL from which I can evaluate the HTML and pull data as I need for listing a visual.

Link to site I am wanting to simulate [here](https://signin.ea.com/p/web/login?execution=e2074126973s1&initref=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.ea.com%3A443%2Fconnect%2Fauth%3Fscope%3Dbasic.identity%2Bbasic.persona%2Boffline%2Bbasic.domaindata%2Bbasic.utility%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.easports.com%252Fsignin_check%26locale%3Den_us%26state%3D7f5c88d174c8665a29c5c5aca9c6c47bd7315148%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%3DEASPORTS-DOT-COM-Web-Client)

Since I am wanting to display a more friendly GUI over the webbrowser, I believe I can modify the HTML of the browser with this  `WebBrowser1.EvaluateJavaScript(ChangeElementByIDforPassandUsername_String);`
where the passed string it taken from TEdits on the form.

following this here: 
http://blogs.embarcadero.com/nikolay/2014/04/17/exampleofusingjavascriptforgooglemapsinthedelphixe6/

But then how can I invoke a simulated buttonclick on the site for the login button?

Answer (score 1):

Forget hijacking a mobile browser. Use Indy's `TIdHTTP` component to send HTTP `POST` requests to the server as needed.  Use a normal WebBrowser to look at the live HTML and then code the relevant fields into your app.  Or use `TIdHTTP` to download the HTML and analyze it in code.  But either way, you can use your own UI.

For example:

```
var
  PostData: TStringList;
  Resp: String;
begin
  PostData := TStringList.Create;
  try
    PostData.Add('email=...');
    PostData.Add('password=...');
    PostData.Add('_eventId=submit');
    PostData.Add('facebookAuth=');

    // make sure a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL is assigned
    // to the TIdHTTP.IOHandler property beforehand

    Resp := IdHTTP1.Post(URL{'https://signin.ea.com/p/web/login?execution=...'}, PostData);
  finally
    PostData.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I tried using INDY post at first, and even included the proper SSL requirements for simulator/mobile but I couldnt get it to work. I just not tried sending a post request in 'Postman' app for Google Chrome, but I can not get it to work via post request there either. Using same params as you just shown above ^^ but with credentials I know work.

Comment: I know for a fact that Indy's `TIdHTTP` and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` components work fine on mobile, so my guess is that you simply did not `POST` the correct field data that the site was expecting. Use a packet sniffer to see how a normal WebBrowser posts them, then replicate that same data in your code.

Comment: I agree. Okay, I will try that suggestion. Thanks